# RegEx get tr tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the string:

```
'
<tr id="sdf"></tr>
<td>
  <div>asdf</div>
  asdf
</td>
<tr id="sdfdf">
  <td>
    <div>asdf</div>
    asdf
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="sdf"></tr>
<tr id="ssdfdf">
  <td>
    <div>asdf</div>
    asdf
  </td>
</tr>
'
```

and I'd like to save `tr` tags into an array using RegExp.

Comment: On what? An elephant? A wart? Is this an XHTML question? What is the source data? What do you want to do with the result? Also, parsing XHTML with Regex is almost always wrong.

Comment: By using a HTML parser... you have to provide a *lot* more information.

Comment: I will store tr tags in the array and then send their by portions.

Comment: @Alexander: Do you practise being vague?

Comment: Be gentle Tomalak, he doesn't sound like a native English speaker. But Alexader, we need more information. Are you looking for content within the tr tags, are you looking for the entire element with the content? Tell us what exactly you're trying to do. Chances are, someone will tell you a better way to get it done.

Comment: When I use "<tr.+</tr>" it return me incorrect answer. It does not take into account that tr tag cannot contain another tr tags.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Providing no pertinent information is orthogonal to the language in which you didn't provide it.

Comment: @Alexander: Look at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288277/javascript-regex-for-div-tags) and do it for `tr` rather than `div`.

Comment: I have next string: "<tr id="sdf"></tr><td><div>asdf</div>asdf</td><tr id="sdfdf"><td><div>asdf</div>asdf</td></tr><tr id="sdf"></tr><tr id="ssdfdf"><td><div>asdf</div>asdf</td></tr>". I want to save tr tags into array by using RegExp.

Comment: Alexander, rewrite the question with some sample data, tell us what output to expect.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal thanks. Answer was <\s*tr[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*tr>

Comment: @Alexander: No, the real answer is that you shouldn't parse HTML with regex and there's never really a need to. :) Walk the DOM instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as `<tr>` tags are never nested, you could try this:

```
result = subject.match(/<tr[\s\S]*?<\/tr>/g);
```

This gets you an array of all `<tr>` tags and their contents.

`[\s\S]` is the JavaScript way of saying "any character, including newlines", and `*?` asks for zero or more repetitions of that, trying to use as few as possible to avoid matching across multiple tags at once.

This blows up as soon as `<tr>` tags are nested, though, which is one of the reasons why regexes are not the best tool for parsing markup languages (to put it mildly). You will get more reliable results by parsing the DOM.