# jquery: Keep <script> tag after .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add ajax to WordPress by jquery-ajaxy plugin, and I'm stuck with one thing:

My page is loaded by ajax call, filtered, and appended to dom. So in short, it would be:

```
data = this.state.Response.data; //full html of page returned by ajax
$mainContent = $(data).find("#content"); //we filter out what we need 
$('#content_div').append($mainContent); //we display it
```

Easy for now, but there are inline js scripts in $mainContent, which are striped by jquery.
I need them, somehow.

It all works, if I just do

```
.append(data);
```

But data contains full html (doctype, head, meta) which I can't append. 
So, is there a way to make those  tags work after `.find()`?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you create a jQuery object from a string, script tags are automatically stripped. You can see a discussion in here: [JavaScript RegEx for div tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288277/javascript-regex-for-div-tags)

What I would do, as suggested in a post in the thread above, is to wrap the content in special comment tags and use javascript `match()` to extract it, the append the whole string.

```
data = this.state.Response.data; //full html of page returned by ajax

//Assuming your data looks like: ...<!--Content Start-->CONTENT<!--Content End-->...
//we filter out what we need 
data = data.match(/<\!\-\-Content Start\-\->(.*?)<\!\-\-Content End\-\->/)[1];

$('#content_div').append(data); //we display it
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [jQuery Filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of find method.