# jQuery: Issue Using .find() Command

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm passing the entire HTML contents of an external web page to a javascript variable ("myHTML"). Next, I'm trying to determine whether two different tags with specific attributes exist within the myHTML variable. I'm looking for the existence of a certain `<div>` tag and `<script>` tag. I am able to identify the `<div>` tag:

```
alert($(myHTML).find('div[id^="myID"]').length)
```

The above code returns the correct count.  However, I am unable to find the `<script>` tag (even though it does exist on the page / in the myHTML variable):

```
alert($(myHTML).find('script[src*="example.com"]').length)
```

The above code always returns zero, even though there is a `<script>` tag with a src attribute pointing to "...example.com/...".

Can anyone explain why the first line of code works, while the second line fails? Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: What do you get if you just try `console.log($(myHTML).find('script').length)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was discussed before in here: [jquery: Keep <script> tag after .find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791420/jquery-keep-script-tag-after-find/5792518#5792518)

jQuery strips all script tags whenever you create a jQuery object from a string. The solution is to parse the string using regular expressions before you turn it into an object.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I use a regex to find the desired script tag, is there any way to ensure that I am not matching a script tag that is commented out (unlikely to happen, but possible)?

Comment: You can use a pre-processing regex to remove all commented out parts from your HTML before searching for the script.