# javascript not working in the new part when loading a new part using jquery and HTML 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Hi as my title suggest, i use the following code to dynamically load a portion of the page (here left id)

```
function callBackFunctionLoadNextBackInPage(data)
{
    //alert(data);
    $("#left").fadeTo(100,1);
    var data = $(data).find( '#left' );
    $("#left").html(data);
    if(supports_history_api())
    {
        history.pushState(null, null, loadNextBackInPage_URL);  
        if(!popEventListnerAdded) {
            window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
            loadNextBackInPage(location.href);
            },false);
            popEventListnerAdded = true;
        }

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
function loadNextBackInPage(url,parm)
{
    //alert(url);
    loadNextBackInPage_URL = url;
    $("#left").fadeTo(100,.2);
    $.post(url,parm,callBackFunctionLoadNextBackInPage,'html');
}
```

Here is [an example of how i do it](http://bedupako.com/songs.php) (click on the show details link

Problem is:

It loads properly... but the javascript is not working. For example: 1. I use a discuss for comments and it doesnt load in the following section

> Add a Comment using Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo!, DISQUS, OpenID or Anonymus

But if you refresh the browser it does load properly... I am loading all the scripts required first only... so why is it not working?

Also for example: The SHARE (Click here) button should expand using the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHideDiv()
{
    var divstyle = new String();
    divstyle = document.getElementById("share").style.display;
    if(divstyle.toLowerCase()=="block" || divstyle == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("share").style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("share").style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
```

But it doesnot!... but works if i refresh the page(i.e load the url again)

Mainly i want the discuss commenting thing to work. I use the following codes to generate it

```
<div class="entry">
  <h2>Add a Comment using Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo!, DISQUS, OpenID or Anonymus </h2>
  <p>


  <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = '[written here]'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

    // The following are highly recommended additional parameters. Remove the slashes in front to use.
     var disqus_identifier = 'page=show_song_details.php&songid=<?php echo $sid ?>&n=0&back=no';
     var disqus_url = '<?php echo $main_root.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>';
    var disqus_developer = 1 ;
    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>

  </p>


</div>
```

Comment: no one is able to pin point the problem till now :( any tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery strips out `<script>` tags whenever you create a jQuery object from a HTML string to do some DOM manipulations on it, in your case `.find()`.

Your best bet is to read the whole HTML as text, then use regular expressions to chop it up and put the relevant part into your document. You should also think about redesigning part of your project, as in my opinion loading parts of an external page with partial scripts is not a good practice and could be hard to maintain in the long term. Unless of course it's a well thought out modular design you've got there and you know what you're doing.

This issue is an exact duplicate of a different thread, although I can't vote to close it due to the bounty. Have a look at my answer here and see if it helps: [jquery: Keep <script> tag after .find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791420/jquery-keep-script-tag-after-find/5792518#5792518)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is the order in which your events are firing. When you load the page normally, the discuss js is most likely run when `load` fires.  So when you load with ajax, it won't fire the `load` event. Instead, you will have to initialize these compontent in you callBackFunctionLoadNextBackInPage method or use another callback.

```
$.post(url,parm,function(data) {
    callBackFunctionLoadNextBackInPage(data);

    // Initialize here
    $('.element').plugin_initializer();

},'html');
```

Comment: I have tried you edit... and it may solve some problems but not all. I wanted the JS in the <div id="left"> to work due to my implementation reasons and also to keep the JS in single place so that i can maintain more easily

Answer (score 0):

The function `showHideDiv()` is not availbe on the main page (list) and is only on the sub page (individual song).
In the following code you are retrieving only a subset of the page's dom which means the JS functions you've created in the rest of the page aren't run.

```
$("#left").fadeTo(100,1);
var data = $(data).find( '#left' );
$("#left").html(data);
```

You can fix this by including the JS functions you need in the main page.

A possible solution I read about ages ago would be to assign the function to a variable like so:

```
var showHideDiv = function() {...};
```

This makes me feel a bit dirty... but what about running an eval on `data`. Something like:

```
$("#left").fadeTo(100,1);
var data = $(data).find( '#left' );
$("#left").html(data);

data.find('script').each(function() {
  eval($(this).text());
});
```

**Edit:** Perhaps you could try jQuery's `globalEval` function a try.

```
$("#left").fadeTo(100,1);
var data = $(data).find( '#left' );
$("#left").html(data);

data.find('script').each(function() {
  $.globalEval($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: no the JS function is inside the "left" ID div tag... and cos i replace the whole left div i assume that even JS function gets included right?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a possible fix. Please give it a try.

Comment: alas :( i implemented the same and its still the same problem... you can check out the replaced code

Comment: :P thanks again for your patience... But still doesnt work. I just did a work around by puting the showHideDiv() func in a separate file of its own and loading it in the main page itself... But the main problem for me is NOT this little function. I want the discuss comments to work. I have added the piece of code i use for it. Why is that not working?

Comment: well i edited my question to include the code i talked about in the previous comment

Comment: mystirious tho it may sound ... after i put an alert inside the function you wrote to find and evaluate each sfcrip i found its not running at all... Even a modified code of $(data).find('script').each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
   eval($(this).text());
 }); wont work :(

Comment: Updated my answer to use the `globalEval` function.

Comment: Well even this is not working... :( the problem is its not even going inside the data.find('script').each().. its as if there is no script tag even tho it is there

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing onclick with jquery live() and see if it wokrs. Also your showHideDiv could be reduced to one line:

```
$("#share").toggle()
```

Comment: sure :) but thats the least of my worries as the real problem is the script not running in the sub page even tho its in the left div

Comment: and it doesnt work that way.... besides mainly i want the discuss commenting thing to work