# Javascript doesn't work when loading a page via ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript not working in the new part when loading a new part using jquery and HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173570/javascript-not-working-in-the-new-part-when-loading-a-new-part-using-jquery-and)

I loaded another HTML page into a div of the main HTML page using Ajax. The page loaded fine, but when I try to apply jQUery to the loaded page, nothing works.

```
$('.mainDiv').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.secondDiv').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000'+url);
});
```

I tried using a simple alert function called on all links to see if it works, but the alert appears only on the main page links, even though the .js file is linked to both pages.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert('hey');
});
```

How can I fix this? Would using .live() or .on() instead of .load() fix the problem?

Comment: .live or .on would work, though not inplace of .load. The problem is the script is executing before the html is being added to the DOM. This is what i would consider a little more advanced, and worth using $.ajax rather than $.load. with $.ajax, you can separate the scripts from the html, append the html, then execute the scripts.

Comment: @KevinB: Use `.on` rather than `.live`. `.live` is deprecated.

Comment: @MattBurland Of course... did i suggest one over the other? I didn't intend to, i simply responded to the question at the bottom.

Comment: @KevinB: You did not suggest one over the other. That was kind of my point. You should recommend `.on` over `.live`. We should steer people away from depreciated features.

Comment: @MattBurland I don't feel SO is the place for that. You and many others may disagree, but this is my stance on it.

Comment: `.on` vs `.live` has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `$('body').on('click', 'a', function(event){...})` would work.

Because `on` is called on the `<body>` you don't need to worry about the event getting wiped out when you load in new content.

If you would like to scope this event on a specific set of anchors I would suggest name spacing with a class in the second parameter using something like

```
$('body').on('click', '.mainDiv .secondDiv a', function(event){...})
```

By setting this once in a bootstrap you can reduce a lot of complexity within your code. Now all you need to do is load in the content; there is no need to define a callback inline as you've extracted out the event logic.

`$('a').on(...)` will **not** work as the DOM element it's bound to may get wiped out, or is not on the page at the time of the call. The 2nd parameter of the `on` call is used to reference any new elements appearing under the root element (`body` in this case).

Comment: Hey Daniel, shouldn't it be `$('.secondDiv').on` instead of body? I mean he wouldn't want all the anchor tags in the body to behave the same way, he is trying to test the binding of the new anchor tags he loaded through AJAX.

Comment: @PulkitMittal - Yeah, you can scope it that way. I mention above, if you go the body route you prevent the possibility of your events getting wiped out via another action from within your app that killed the `$('.secondDiv')` element.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do:

```
$('.secondDiv').on('click', 'a', function() {
    alert('hey');
});
```

So basically every dynamic anchor tag loaded in secondDiv will be binded to this function automatically. Otherwise what you could have done is:

```
$('.secondDiv').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000'+url, function(){
    $(this).find('a').click(function(){
        alert('hey');
    });    
});
```

But I would not suggest you the latter, if the first one works fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kevin B that $.ajax() might be better here. Then you can set up your click event in the callback.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+url,
   dataType: 'html',
   succcess: function(data){
      $('.secondDiv').append(data);
      $('.secondDiv a').click(function(){
         alert('hey');
      });
   }
});
```